# How to reference a function after an argument in CodeIgniter URLs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

My desired URL structure for a section of a web application is as follows:
`/user/FooBar42/edit/privacy`, and I would like this to route to controller: user, function: edit, with `FooBar42` and `privacy` as arguments (in that order). **How should I accomplish this with CodeIgniter?**

Comment: `routes['user/(:any)'] = user/edit/$1/$2`
on config/routes

Comment: Why not just put the URL in the proper order?

Comment: @J.Money Define *proper order*. We have determined that the best UX design for URLs in our application follows the order I described, regardless of how CodeIgniter decided they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the remapping option of the CI controller

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

and doing something like this:

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
    // check if the method exists
    if (method_exists($this, $method))
    {
        // run the method
         return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }
    else
    {
     // method does not exists so you can call nay other method you want
     $this->edit($params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Defining this [route](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) in `application/config/routes.php` should work:

```
$route['user/(:any)/edit/(:any)'] = "user/edit/$1/$2";
```

However, be aware that `(:any)` in the above route would match multiple segments. For example, `user/one/two/edit/three` would call the `edit` function in the `user` controller but only pass `one` as the fist parameter and `two` as the second.

Replacing the `(:any)` with the regex `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` will only allow one only *alphanumeric values of length at least 1*. This mitigates the issue above, where a `/` would be permitted allowing multiple segments to be allowed. Now, if `user/one/two/edit/three` was used, a 404 page would be shown.

```
$route['user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/edit/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = "user/edit/$1/$2";
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you just FYI. Question though, would this route a URL like `user/login`, or only routes that match that rule?

Comment: I believe it would not route something like `user/login`, it should only route URLs that match that rule. So, if the URL had segments as `user/login`, it should still call the `login` function in the `user` controller.

Comment: `(:any)` will match anything including '/' so putting `user/(:any)/edit/(:any)` is completely redundant , if you would like to do this just use a regular expression,

Comment: @tomexsans: Depends on the CI version 2.x `(:any)` is equal to `(.+)` in 3.x it is equal to `([^/]+)`